# How to use form login with Rest Assured with Spring MVC/Thymeleaf?

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf, rest-assured

I have a Spring Boot 2.1.4 application using Thymeleaf with a fairly standard login form:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" th:action="@{/login}" method="post">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" th:placeholder="#{username}"/>
  <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" th:placeholder="#{password}"/>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-md action-button-primary" th:text="#{login}"></button>
</form>
```

When starting the application, this all works fine and I can log on.

I now want to write an integration test using Rest Assured that accesses a secured page.

```
given().auth()
       .form("admin", "admin",
              new FormAuthConfig("/login", "username", "password")
                .withLoggingEnabled()
                .withAutoDetectionOfCsrf())
    .when()
    .get("/people")
    .then()
    .log()
    .all().assertThat().statusCode(HttpStatus.SC_OK);
```

I see in the logging that a `POST` request is done:

```
Request method: POST
Request URI:    http://localhost:58352/login
Proxy:          <none>
Request params: <none>
Query params:   <none>
Form params:    username=admin
                password=admin
                _csrf=2296f8a3-39a5-48b2-99ec-a20ed01cfeec
Path params:    <none>
Headers:        Accept=*/*
                Content-Type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=ISO-8859-1
```

However, Rest Assured never ends up at the `/people` page. It seems it gets redirected to `/login` again.

If I enable the Spring Security debug logging, I see:

```
CsrfFilter - Invalid CSRF token found for http://localhost:58352/login
```

My assumption is that Rest Assured is somehow using the wrong CSRF token? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the field name "_csrf" or is it different in the application ?

Comment: The field name is indeed `_csrf`. I don't have a hidden input in my Thymleaf explictly as Thymeleaf seems to add this itself. I did try adding it manually, but then Rest Assured gave me an exception because the HTML contained 2 fields named `_csrf` if I did that.

Comment: alright, I seem to find no mistake but reading through the question again I see you have mentioned that the page gets redirected to /login ( I don't suppose this is the expected ? ) Can you try with given().redirects().follow(false)